# Extra 'data' argument in call

Tags: swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

i have the following UILabel and i want to apply html text

```
    var htmlText = "<b><i>sample text</i></b>"
    var attrStr = NSAttributedString(
        data: htmlText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil,
        error: nil)
    label.attributedText = attrStr
```

the compiler send this Extra 'data' argument in call

any ideas?

Comment: what version of XCode are you using? This is not reporting an error for me in a playground on 6.1.

Comment: xcode 6.1 not using playground

Comment: does it actually not compile? Sometimes you can get ghost errors that don't actually stop the build. Does this work for *you*, in a playground?

Comment: yes it works very strange

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, except that I was supplying an empty dictionary for the options parameter.

```
  if let string = NSAttributedString(data: data,
    options: [],
    documentAttributes: nil,
    error: &error) {
      self.textView.attributedText = string
  }
```

When I switched it to `nil` instead, the compiler stopped complaining.

```
  if let string = NSAttributedString(data: data,
    options: nil,
    documentAttributes: nil,
    error: &error) {
      self.textView.attributedText = string
  }
```

You may need to case the options dictionary to `[NSObject : AnyObject]`, since that is the type for that parameter.